# Amazon Neptune Gremlin Query ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.Long

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am using the Java client for Neptune provided here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-java.html

And I am trying to execute the following query:

```
List<Map<Object, Object>> queriedList = g.V().has("name", "exampleName").valueMap().toList()
```

However, I am encountering a

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.Long
```

at

```
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.Traversal.toList(Traversal.java:122)
```

This is very strange because I do not have any Integer or Long involved in this query. When I tried to print out the valueMap, it gave me

```
[GraphStep(vertex,[]), HasStep([name.eq(exampleName)]), PropertyMapStep(value)]"
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the full stack trace if you are able to add that to the question.